# How to access text inside nested divs?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to access certain text properties that are nested. Have had no trouble with most elements, but just haven't been able to get a certain few.

I'm trying to set:
 one variable = Optomi, another variable = Detroit, Michigan, United States (Although I feel like once I have the first variable, I can get the second fairly easy)

[Full Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwgsT.png)

```
<a data-control-name="company_link" href="/company/optomi/life/" id="ember2228" class="jobs-details-top-card__company-url ember-view"> Optomi </a>
```

I'm trying to just pull out the text value "Optomi".

I've tried:

```
cname = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='jobs-details-top-card__company-url ember-view']/a")
print(cname)
```

and

```
cname = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
          "div.jobs-details-top-card__company-info t-14 t-black--light t-normal mt1")
print(cname)
print(cname.get_attribute("text"))
```

Any tips?

Comment: Try `cname = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='jobs-details-top-ard__company-url ember-view']").text`

Comment: Why the `/a` in your xpath?

Comment: @AMC Error on my part, good catch!

Comment: @CC7052 Will try, thank you!

Comment: @CC7052 Returns a noSuchElementException error

Answer (score 0):

Try using what CC7052 said:

```
cname = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='jobs-details-top-ard__company-url ember-view']").text
```

and then maybe use .split for getting Detroit

```
cname.split(',')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried it, but it just returns an error message:
 ```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='jobs-details-top-ard__company-url ember-view']"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pull out the text **Optomi** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.jobs-details-top-card__company-url.ember-view[data-control-name='company_link'][href*='optomi']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='jobs-details-top-card__company-url ember-view' and @data-control-name='company_link'][contains(@href,'optomi')]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```